# beracha, kavanos and words

Tags: halacha, blessing, kavana-concentration

When making a *berachah* must one have certain *kavanos* on certain words in the berachah that he is saying in order to be יוצא it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 5-1):

> When one says a blessing, he should have in mind the meaning of the
>   words.  When one says the name (of G-d), he should have in mind the
>   meaning of what he is saying[1].  When one mentions the Lordship of
>   G-d, he should have in mind that he is the master of everything.  When
>   it is written yud-kay-vav-kay, he should have in mind that G-d is,
>   was, and will be[2].  When one says אלקים, he should have in mind that
>   He can do anything and is the Master of all strength.

M.B. writes that it is imperative to completely understand what one is saying.  See Yeshayah 29:13 where G-d relates how he was angry at Israel “Since this people approach with their mouth and with their lips honoring me but their heart is far away from me
(I believe the Vilna Gaon only requires this kavana of elokeinu by shema)

Comment: Where does the Mishnah Berurah say this?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, one has to concentrate on the meaning of the words, as the Shulchan Aruch says in Siman 5 - סימן ה - כונת הברכות:

> יְכַוֵּן בַּבְּרָכוֹת פֵּרוּשׁ הַמִּלּוֹת

The Shulchan Aruch then tells us what tink about when mentioning Hashem's names:

> , כְּשֶׁיַּזְכִּיר הַשֵּׁם יְכַוֵּן פֵּרוּשׁ קְרִיאָתוֹ בְּאַדְנוּת, שֶׁהוּא אֲדוֹן הַכֹּל וִיכַוֵּן בִּכְתִיבָתוֹ בְּיוֹ''ד הֵ '' א  שֶׁהָיָה וְהֹוֶה וְיִהְיֶה. וּבְהַזְכִּירוֹ אֱ-לֹהִים יְכַוֵּן שֶׁהוּא תַּקִּיף בַּעַל הַיְכֹלֶת, וּבַעַל הַכֹּחוֹת כֻּלָּם: ‏

When saying the "Adon" name of Hashem one should realize he is the master of the Universe. If it's written with Yud-Hey then one adds the thought that "He was, is and will be".

When saying the "Elokim" name one thinks about the fact that He is the Almighty who runs everything.

I have not seen anybody mention that one is not יוצא if one does not have these intentions.

As far as any socifc Bracha goes:

See the begining of the first Se'if in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן ו - קצת דיני ברכות ודיני ברוך הוא וברוך שמו ואמן which says:

> קֹדֶם שֶׁיְּבָרֵךְ אֵיזוֹ בְרָכָה צָרִיךְ הוּא לָדַעַת אֵיזוֹ בְרָכָה שֶׁהוּא צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ, כְּדֵי שֶׁבְּשָׁעָה שֶׁהוּא מַזְכִּיר אֶת הַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ שֶׁהוּא עִקַּר הַבְּרָכָה, יֵדַע מַה שֶּׁיְּסַיֵּם. ‏

"**Before making a Bracha one has to know which Bracha needs to be said, so that when mentioning Hashem's name - which is the main part of the Bracha - he knows how the Bracha ends.**"

That said, even if you err in your kavana and were planning on making a different Bracha - or even if you actually made the wrong Bracha and immediately fixed it - **the Bracha is still valid, despite the mistake in Kavana.**

As the Kitzur says in סימן נו - דין טעות בברכות :

> סעיף ה': אַף עַל פִּי **שֶׁלְּכַתְּחִלָּה צָרִיךְ לְדַקְדֵק וּלְכַוֵּן עַל מַה שֶּׁהוּא מְבָרֵךְ**  מִכָּל מָקוֹם בְּדִיעֲבַד אִם טָעָה בַּכַּוָּנָה, כְּגוֹן שֶׁלָּקַח בְּיָדוֹ כּוֹס קָסָבַר שֶׁהוּא יַיִן, וּבֵרַךְ עַל דַּעַת, שֶׁהוּא יַיִן, וְקֹדֶם שֶׁאָמַר בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן נִזְכַּר שֶׁהוּא מַיִם אוֹ שֵׁכָר וְסִיֵּם שֶׁהַכֹּל נִהְיָה בִּדְבָרוֹ, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לַחֲזוֹר וּלְבָרֵךְ, **דְּמִשּׁוּם טָעוּת בְּכַּוָּנָה אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לַחֲזוֹר וּלְבָרֵךְ**. וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן אִם טָעָה בְּהִפּוּךְ, שֶׁהָיָה סָבוּר שֶׁהוּא שֵׁכָר אוֹ מַיִם וּבֵרַךְ עַל דַּעַת לוֹמַר שֶׁהַכֹּל, וְקֹדֶם שֶׁאָמַר שֶׁהַכֹּל נִזְכַּר שֶׁהוּא יַיִן, וְסִיֵּם בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן, שֶׁיָּצָא. שֶׁהֲרֵי אֲפִלּוּ אִם הָיָה מְסַיֵּם כְּפִי הַכַּוָּנָה הָיָה יוֹצֵא. ‏
>
> סעיף ו': **אֲפִלּוּ אִם סִיֵּם כָּל הַבְּרָכָה בְּטָעוּת, אֶלָּא שֶׁנִּזְכַּר תּוֹךְ כְּדֵי דִּבּוּר וְתִקֵּן אֲמִירָתוֹ**, כְּגוֹן שֶׁלָּקַח כּוֹס מַיִם אוֹ שֵׁכָר קָסָבַר שֶׁהוּא יַיִן וּבֵרַךְ בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן, וְנִזְכַּר מִיָּד שֶׁהוּא מַיִם אוֹ שֵׁכָר וְסִיֵּם שֶׁהַכֹּל נִהְיָה בִּדְבָרוֹ, וְכָךְ הָיְתָה אֲמִירָתוֹ, בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן שֶׁהַכֹּל נִהְיָה בִּדְבָרוֹ, **יָצָא**. ‏

Comment: Is there any kavana that one has to have when saying the word(s) baruch, atah or y-k-vk?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - I added to the [top of the] answer.